# Loading failed for the module with source “http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/js/Pages/Ads/Index.vue?t=1670962685226”. Using Inertia, VueJS and Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am currently developing a CRUD application using Laravel 9, InertiaJS and VueJS.

When I try to go to the route `/ads` I have the following error message in the console :
[image]

My index page is in /Pages/Ads/Index.vue

The code of my route (web.php) is :

```
Route::resource('ads', AdController::class);
```

The code of my controller is :

```
class AdController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $ads = Ad::with(['model','user'])->get();
        return inertia('Ads/Index', compact('ads'));
    }
}
```

The code of my Pages/Ads/Index.vue is :

```
<template>
    <h1>Index ad</h1>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Index ad',
    props: {
        ads: Object,
    },
}
</script>
```

I don't understand why I have this error, because I have other routes working and rendering properly Vue pages.
I check the Laravel and Inertia documentation but I didn't found the issue.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

I tried to look the at the differences with my code that is working with other routes, I checked the Laravel and Inertia documentation, and look online same issues.

Comment: do u have any ad blocker?

Comment: Yess, and it was the problem, I disabled it and now it works, thanks a lot ! :)